# Javascript Date() giving wrong value

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

The Unix epoch time `1354341600` translates to `GMT: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 06:00:00 GMT` (via http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Doing `new Date(1354341600)` on Javascript `Fri Jan 16 1970 10:12:21 GMT-0600 (CST)` (I'm in Illinois)

Relevant JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DAQkZ/

How do I get the correct Date/time in Javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gotta multiply by 1000... to get milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970

```
alert(new Date(1354341600*1000));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the units you're using. 
The "Time from epoch" is in seconds, and the JS Date is expecting Milliseconds.

Try this:

```
alert(new Date(1354341600000));
```

Answer (score 1):

the time you are getting is in seconds. you need it in mili seconds or you can use another format

var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);

your off by 1000, so multiply by 1000. or use a different format from the ones above.